# How do I reward someone for helping when they didn't provide the correct answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, reputation

**The question**

If someone provides useful comments -- or even a useful answer! -- but **not the correct answer in my case**, what is the preferred means of rewarding them?

I can't imagine it's upvoting the incorrect answer. Is it upvoting one of the comments? Is it upvoting each of the comments? Is it something else that hasn't crossed my mind?

**The context**

This question stems from a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38555781/why-is-my-elastic-beanstalk-app-denied-putitem-access-to-my-dynamodb-despite-it) that I posed earlier today. One user in particular was very helpful in providing suggestions, although the answer they posed did not solve my particular problem.

That being said, the suggestions certainly could have provided the solution, and they at least got me thinking in a different direction. I want to reward (read: provide incentive) for this sort of good behavior, but I'm not sure what the best practices are for doing so.

In my view, this person deserves at least as much of a reward as a correct answer in a low-view question, because of the time they clearly put in. I hope there's a way I can provide them with at least a fraction of that.

**Thank you!**

Comment: Why would you want to actually? Giving upvotes is lean anyways ...

Comment: Upvote and comment.

Comment: Upvote, and self-answer (possible community wiki) with a link back to that user's post(s).

Comment: *Unrelated but good to know:* It's discouraged to write things like "Thanks" or "Any help appreciated" at the ends of questions.

Comment: And I guess the context meant to talk about a question you posTed earlier that day. I tried to edit it, but couldn't.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/c85sAzj.png

Comment: @Lomefin: "... a question I *posed* ..." is still both grammatically correct and contextually appropriate.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The upvote tooltip for answers literally says "This answer is useful".

If you find an answer useful, upvote it. **If it is factually wrong, then it's not useful, it's misleading.**

However if, for example, it seems like a good way of troubleshooting the problems you have, there's no harm in upvoting. Even though it ended up not leading you to the root cause of your problems.

Comment: This is most concise (and, I think, official) answer to the question. It's okay to upvote a useful answer, even if it's not the right one -- although correctness is a requirement for *acceptance*.

Comment: In these cases, an explanatory comment is helpful to describe why you upvoted and to indicate to other readers that the answer is not necessarily correct. Perhaps an edit to the answer could then be made (either by the answerer or the community) .

Answer (score 16):

> this person [who wrote a useful but incorrect answer] deserves at least as much of a reward as a correct answer in a low-view question

No, he doesn't. A crappy answer that solves your problem is better than an awesome answer that doesn't solve your problem.

You should accept the answer that works and simply leave an upvote on the answer that is useful but doesn't work.

Comment: Well a *crappy answer that solves his problem* is only useful for the OP, while an *awesome answer that doesn't solve his problem* can be pretty much helpful to the OP, i.e. directing him into the right path, *and* helping the rest of the community. Sometimes people ask questions too specific to their case, I discourage that.

Comment: Note: [The VLQ flag is for trash that's completely unintelligible.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93595/295684) If an answer conveys any meaning at all, it shouldn't be flagged as VLQ.

Answer (score 15):

You can reward them by leaving a nice comment.

> *Hey thanks! This helped get me on the right track.*

For the poster, who was trying to be helpful, this is still a big win, even though they did not post a valid answer (at least it was helpful).

As pointed out in the comments for this post, the above example does not provide much feedback as to why you did not accept or upvote, so it does not add value to the post. Consider expanding your comment to discuss your reasoning, or suggest a way that the answer can be improved to be more accurate. For example:

> *Hey Thanks! Your example for part B got me on the right track, but part A is incorrect/misleading. Specifically...*

Comment: I think the reason this answer is getting both upvotes and downvotes is that (1) commenting *might* be the most appropriate response, but (2) the example comment shown here is just barely better than "Thanks! +1" or "Useful answer", both of which are discouraged as they add more clutter than value. If you are going to comment (which I think is fine), then be a lot more specific and point out exactly what helped, and also be specific and point out why the answer isn't *fully correct* (which is why OP is hesitating to upvote it).

Answer (score 8):

You should not upvote the incorrect answer just to award some reputation. Try to focus on the content rather than on the author. The voting system, although it has its flaws, is designed to encourage the generation of good content.

The help center summarizes the reasons for [voting up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) a post or a comment:

> #### When should I vote up?
>
> Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment that you feel is especially useful, vote it up!

And, from [*Why is voting important?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote):

> Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful *[...]* The more that people vote on a post, the more certain future visitors can be of the quality of information contained within that post – not to mention that upvotes are a great way to thank the author of a good post for the time and effort put into writing it!

If the user's answer is incorrect, it certainly doesn't deserve any merits. This would only trick future readers into the false illusion, that this might be a viable solution to the problem. If, on the other hand, the comments by the same author, or any other, were helpful solving your issue, you could indicate that by upvoting those comments.

A user, who is after earning reputation, should be aware that this requires providing useful, high-quality content. Even if a user posted an initially incorrect answer and continues to further contribute in finding the correct solution via comments, they are free at any time to edit their own post accordingly. No one requires you to write *the* one-shot, spot-on answer. In fact, many of the great answers around show at least some kind of evolution.

That said, if you want to get the most out of your question for the community *and* award some reputation points to the contributor, you could comment on that answer and kindly ask them to improve their post. Ideally, this would not only include the final solution but also summarize the approach that did not work.

You are then free to accept the answer, upvote it, and, if it is really great, you might even award a bounty to it.

Comment: This is the only _completely_ correct answer here.

Comment: Is funny that the accepted answer is orthogonally opposite to the other 3 answers and yet it have a single downvote.