# Clicking a response as helpful returns as Answer?

Tags: support

I recently upticked a couple of responses to my question as helpful, clicking the up arrow, and clicked another response as the answer because it was the answer. I was surprised to see that the site interpreted that as three answers, the one I clicked as the answer and the other two I clicked as helpful. Is there another way I can just click something as helpful and give them some kind of credit without it being interpreted as the answer, because they weren't quite the answer. Or does it matter?

Here is the post: [Post with 3 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39778868/macro-to-highlight-rows-of-data-does-not-run-in-excel-workbook)

**Poster's Edit 9:11 pm** - I was unable to respond until now but was hoping to click on the link that allowed me to explain why I thought my question was not a duplicate to another post, [How do I reward someone, etc. post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329356/how-do-i-reward-someone-for-helping-when-they-didnt-provide-the-correct-answer).

I would like to defend my question that it was not a duplicate. I know how to upvote--or uptick it as I called it--I mention how to in the first sentence. The other poster's question was, 'How do I reward someone, etc.' My question is, 'Does clicking helpful/upvoting a response register it as an answer, etc.'.

I read all of the answers and comments in the linked post, and they all explained about how to reward someone, e.g., upvote or post a comment to say thank you (some disagreed). Even the last answer from a help file said, 'When do I upvote?', and the answers didn't answer my question, 'Does clicking helpful/upvoting a response register it as an answer, etc.'.

It was only until I read @Don't Panic, @animuson, and @Ed Cottrell from my post did I explicitly read that they are called "answers", but it 'does not necessarily mean that those posts solved your problem'. And 'only one [answer] gets marked as accepted'. I had to read all of the posts mentioned above to understand the answer to my question. I didn't get that information from any other post.

Thank you.

Comment: There are three answers there. Only one gets marked as *accepted*.

Comment: you seem to confuse upvote ("hey, this answer is helpful. +1") and accepted answer ("THIS solved MY question").

Comment: Meta was designed as a place to have conversations about the use of the site, including misunderstandings such as this one. Why downvote a support post? It makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @TravisJ Does the hover text, "does not show any research effort" apply to Meta as well? Note: I have not voted on this post.

Comment: To clarify other's comments: there are three answers because that's how many answers people posted. Your actions in voting and marking one as accepted are not what caused the posts to be listed as "answers" -- they were answers before you did anything.

Comment: For futher clarification, a lot of your actions on SO can be predefined by hovering over the button / link. For example, the upvote text for any given answer: "This answer is useful"

Comment: It's just a terminology misunderstanding. When you post a question, each of what you refer to as "responses" are what we refer to as "answers". That is why it says "3 Answers", not because of any actions you took. The fact that they are called "answers" does not necessarily mean that those posts were correct or that they solved your problem; it just means that they were attempts to answer your question. Whether you accept or vote on any of them has not effect on the displayed answer count.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reward someone for helping when they didn't provide the correct answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329356/how-do-i-reward-someone-for-helping-when-they-didnt-provide-the-correct-answer)

Comment: @CubeJockey - Yes, it applies. That said, there is always the availability to make exceptions when users are truly trying to do the right thing and are confused by the way that the site works. Citing RTFM to someone who is just learning how to use the site does not seem to be productive when the issue is trivially solved. It was also tagged support, not discussion. There is a correct answer here.

Comment: Please see my response in my original post.